# Looking for somewhat pooling between average and maximum pooling

Tags: self-study, pooling

In the textbook Dive into Deep, there is a question: Is there another operation between average and maximum pooling that you could consider (hint: recall the softmax)? Why might it not be so popular? ([6.5.5 Exercise 6](https://d2l.ai/chapter_convolutional-neural-networks/pooling.html) ). I have been googling such pooling technique between average and maximum pooling but I still have no idea. Can you provide any source related to such pooling technique?

Comment: I doubt you can google it (because it's not popular/used/works). its just an exercise asking you to come up with an operation inbetween max and average. a typical operation might be raising each input to  odd power (eg 3) and then taking corrresponding root  (ie cube root) of sum of inputs. basically the larger the power the closer you get to maximum (and power 1 is the average)